# I want to search from both Name and Country values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to search on the Name and Country values ​​columns with the text filter, but now I can only search on one column. How can I change the value of `tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0]` to filter on both columns?

I'll be happy if you can help me.

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use datatable js for additional functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can select both fields and ask it to match against either.

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
<table id="myTable">
<tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
// Declare variables
var input, filter, table, tr, tdName, tdCountry, i, txtValueName, txtValueCountry;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

// Hide all table rows initially
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
        continue;
    }
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
}


function myFunction() {
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those that don't match the search query in either the Name or Country column
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        tdName = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        tdCountry = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        if (tdName && tdCountry) {
            txtValueName = tdName.textContent || tdName.innerText;
            txtValueCountry = tdCountry.textContent || tdCountry.innerText;
            if (txtValueName.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || txtValueCountry.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What should I do if I want the <tbody> not to appear when the input is empty? Can you help also with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue,txtValue1;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    td1 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
   
    if (td) {
      txtValue =  td.textContent || td.innerText ;
      txtValue1 =  td1.textContent || td1.innerText ;
       console.log(txtValue1);
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || txtValue1.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with a simpler approach.

Assuming, you want to search the content of the tr itself. I'm looking in the text content for the filter using the includes function. I use the return of that to toggle a class on the tr.

The CSS class sets the display to block, while I also use CSS to set TR to display none by default.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  const trs = table.querySelectorAll("tr:not(.header)");
  
function myFunction() {  
  const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  trs.forEach((tr) => {
      tr.classList.toggle("active",(filter != "" && tr.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter)))
  });
}
```

```css
tr:not(.header){display:none}
tr.active{display:block}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```